# VS Code Disable JSDoc Comment Coloring

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to disable multicolored JSDoc comments in Visual Studio Code.

Currently, the JSDoc comments look like this (`@param`, etc. is colored something other than the default comment color):

[image]

I want the entire comment to be the same default grey color. I tried disabling all extensions and custom user settings, but that didn't affect the JSDoc highlighting. Does anyone know what settings I need to change to fix this? I thought either `workbench.colorCustomizations` or `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` would have the setting I want to change, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Yeah, totally agree - colored JSDoc looks as a part of code which is not. That was always confusing me. Until now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to user Binaryify on the One Dark Pro GitHub for showing me the settings that change the JSDoc highlighting in VS Code! [Link to the GitHub issue](https://github.com/Binaryify/OneDark-Pro/issues/190?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container)

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "name": "storage.type.class.jsdoc",
        "scope":
          "storage.type.class.jsdoc,entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc,variable.other.jsdoc",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#7f848eff"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Replace the "foreground" color with the color you are using for comments. The color used here is the default gray used in the One Dark Pro theme.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! One question though: why is color code consists of 4 bytes, not 3?

Comment: The color code is in the format "#RRGGBBAA". The last byte is the alpha channel.

Comment: how can I disable this feature in php comments?

Comment: Any idea how to color the @ symbol also? Thanks