# Comment highlighting in Visual Studio Code when using JSDoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, comments, jsdoc

In Visual Studio Code, when using [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) comments, how can I ensure that the whole comment block is displayed in *green* (default comment color)?

As is, mine looks like this:

[image]

But I would like it to look like this:

[image]

If it helps, I have installed the [DocumentThis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joelday.docthis) extension, which is where the second screenshot is from.

Comment: It doesn't seem VSCode has a setting for that other than the theme settings. Check [theme-color-reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference), [themes-snippets-colorizers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers) and [themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

[From an older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774920/vs-code-disable-jsdoc-comment-coloring)

Add this to your Settings (File -> Preferences -> Settings)

```
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "name": "storage.type.class.jsdoc",
            "scope":
              "storage.type.class.jsdoc,entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc,variable.other.jsdoc",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#608b4e"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this in the current version (1.69.2)?