# Disable @param and @return colors in the comments on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to disable the colors in the comments and make them all blue.
Here is a picture of colored comments.
[image]

Comment: I believe it's related to the type scheme you're using. Which one is it?

Comment: I'm using Cobalt2, but no it's not related it remains even with the default themes.

Comment: I think you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code to adjust comment colors

Comment: @DorShinar Thanks man I'll try this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774920/vs-code-disable-jsdoc-comment-coloring to disable jsdoc colors and set all jsdoc comment to a single color.