# VSCode : how to disable doxygen tags highlight in comments?

Tags: visual-studio-code, doxygen

In VSCode with no extensions, C files are colored as follow :

[image]

The red square is where I have an issue. I found it distracting to have comments using the same colors as the source code. I would like to find a way to disable doxygen highlights or, at least, dampen its colors to diminished its visual impact.

In an attempt to dampen it, I have been playing with the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` properties (as documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) by Microsoft) to change its colors but I couldn't target the correct group.

A better solution for me would be to disable all Doxygen highlighting. In any way, help will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a general manner, modifying colors of an item in VSCode editor is the following :

1. Place cursor on the visually annoying element.
2. Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to access the palette and search for the `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes`. Select it.
3. Retrieve information in the bullet list at the bottom of the tooltip.
4. Write a textMateRules which scope matches the tooltip scope.

In the case of Doxygen, the following Textmate rule in the `settings.json` file do recolor the Doxygen keywords with a custom color :

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope":"storage.type.class.doxygen",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#6272A4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this only recolor the `@param` tag. For the argument name, we should proceed as listed initially and add the following rule to override its theme color :

```
  {
    "scope": "variable.parameter.c,comment.block.documentation.c",
    "settings": {
      "foreground": "#6272A4"
    }
  }
```

I hope it will be useful other people. For the record, this problem shows up more when searching for JSDoc instead of Doxygen. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774920/vs-code-disable-jsdoc-comment-coloring?rq=1) and its [linked issue](https://github.com/Binaryify/OneDark-Pro/issues/190?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container) allowed me to envision this solution.